# How to speed up finding region centroid and plot3d

Tags: plotting, regions, computational-geometry

I have the following code to make 3D of 9 regions.

```
func1={x<1&&y<1&&z<((1-x)(1-y)),x<1&&y<1&&((x+1)(y+1))<z,x>1&&y<1&&((x+1)(y+1))<z,y>1&&x<1&&((x+1)(y+1))<z,x>1&&y>1&&((x+1)(y+1))<z,x<1&&y>1&&z<((1-x)(y-1)),z<y&&x y>(y+z)&&(x/y)<Min[(1-Sqrt[z/y])^(2),(x^(2)-x-(x z)/y)/(x-1)],y<1&&x>1&&z<((1-y)(x-1)),z<x&&x y>(x+z)&&(y/x)<Min[(1-Sqrt[z/x])^(2),(y^(2)-y-(y z)/x)/(y-1)]};
framelabels1 = TraditionalForm /@ {Abs[Subscript[u, 1]],Abs[Subscript[u, 2]],Abs[Subscript[u, 3]]};
labels1 = Array[Subscript[ℛ, #] &, Length[func1]];
pts1 = RegionCentroid /@ (ImplicitRegion[# && 0 <= x <= 6 && 0 <= y <= 6 && 0 <= z <= 6, {x, y, z}] & /@func1);
Show[RegionPlot3D[func1, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, 0, 6}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Axes -> True,AxesStyle ->Thick, AxesLabel -> framelabels1, ImageSize -> Medium,LabelStyle -> {14, Bold, Black},Mesh -> None,PlotStyle -> (Opacity[1, #] & /@ {Cyan, Blue, Purple, Brown, Green, Yellow,Orange,Magenta,Pink,Gray}),BoxStyle->{Thick},PlotPoints -> 10],Graphics3D[Text[Style[#[[1]], 18,Bold,Red], #[[2]]] & /@ Transpose[{labels1, pts1}]]]
```

I don't know if there is some mistake in the variable `pts1` because Mathematica cannot evaluate it, maybe it is taking too long to find the `RegionCentroid`?

And I have also noticed it takes too long to plot the 3D graphs.

Is there any way to speed up the above two task? maybe by changing the code?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bdrs = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ ImplicitRegion[# && 0 <= x <= 6 && 0 <= y <= 6 && 
       0 <= z <= 6, {x, y, z}] & /@ func1;
pts1 = RegionCentroid /@ bdrs;

Show[MapThread[RegionPlot3D[#, PlotStyle -> #2, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 10] &, 
   {bdrs, Opacity[1, #] & /@ {Cyan, Blue, Purple, Brown, Green, Yellow, 
    Orange, Magenta, Pink}}], 
 Graphics3D[Text[Style[#[[1]], 18, Bold, Red], #[[2]]] & /@ Transpose[{labels1, pts1}]], 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Axes -> True,
  AxesStyle -> Thick, AxesLabel -> framelabels1, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  LabelStyle -> {14, Bold, Black}, BoxStyle -> {Thick}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, perhaps you could toggle the display of regions and/or include legends.

```
$Version

(* "12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

func1 = {
   x < 1 && y < 1 && z < ((1 - x) (1 - y)),
   x < 1 && y < 1 && ((x + 1) (y + 1)) < z,
   x > 1 && y < 1 && ((x + 1) (y + 1)) < z,
   y > 1 && x < 1 && ((x + 1) (y + 1)) < z,
   x > 1 && y > 1 && ((x + 1) (y + 1)) < z,
   x < 1 && y > 1 && z < ((1 - x) (y - 1)),
   z < y && x y > (y + z) && (x/y) < Min[
      (1 - Sqrt[z/y])^(2),
      (x^(2) - x - (x z)/y)/(x - 1)],
   y < 1 && x > 1 && z < ((1 - y) (x - 1)),
   z < x && x y > (x + z) && (y/x) < Min[
      (1 - Sqrt[z/x])^(2),
      (y^(2) - y - (y z)/x)/(y - 1)]};

framelabels1 = 
  TraditionalForm /@ {Abs[Subscript[u, 1]], Abs[Subscript[u, 2]], 
    Abs[Subscript[u, 3]]};

labels1 = Array[Subscript[ℛ, #] &, Length[func1]];

colors = {Cyan, Blue, Purple, Brown, Green,
   Yellow, Orange, Magenta, LightGray};

Manipulate[
 display = Sort@If[display === {},
    Range[Length[func1]], display];
 pltStyle = (Opacity[opacity, #] & /@ colors
    )[[display]];
 RegionPlot3D[
  Evaluate[func1[[display]]],
  {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, 0, 6},
  PlotStyle -> pltStyle,
  Axes -> True,
  AxesStyle -> Thick,
  AxesLabel -> framelabels1,
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  LabelStyle -> {14, Bold, Black},
  Mesh -> None,
  BoxStyle -> Thick,
  PlotPoints -> 30,(* increased PlotPoints *)

  PlotLegends -> labels1[[display]]],
 {{display, Range[Length[func1]]},
  Thread[Range[Length[func1]] -> labels1], ControlType -> CheckboxBar},
 {{opacity, 1}, 0.5, 1, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Prior to version 12.1 `RegionPlot3D` doesn't accept a list of predicates and must be mapped onto the list. The modified `Manipulate` for earlier versions is

```
Manipulate[
 display = Sort@If[display === {}, Range[Length[func1]], display];
 pltStyle = (Opacity[opacity, #] & /@ colors)[[display]];
 arg = Transpose[{func1[[display]], pltStyle}];
 Legended[
  Show[
   RegionPlot3D[#[[1]],
      {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, 0, 6},
      Mesh -> None,
      PlotStyle -> #[[2]],
      PlotPoints -> 30 (*increased PlotPoints*)] & /@
    arg,
   Axes -> True,
   AxesStyle -> Thick,
   AxesLabel -> framelabels1,
   ImageSize -> Medium,
   LabelStyle -> {14, Bold, Black},
   BoxStyle -> Thick],
  SwatchLegend[pltStyle, labels1[[display]]]],
 {{display, Range[Length[func1]]},
  Thread[Range[Length[func1]] -> labels1],
  ControlType -> CheckboxBar},
 {{opacity, 1}, 0.5, 1, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: Hello Your code does not work with MMA 11.3 (Windows) or 12.0 (Mac). Error messages:  RegionPlot3D::boolf  (functions to be plotted by the RegionPlot3D are not a boolean function). Any suggestion?

Comment: @SigisK - see edit for modified `Manipulate`

Comment: Very nice. Thanks